# Is the density of an object time dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, time-evolution

If an untouched (an object whose wavefunction has never collapsed) charged mass has a probability cloud of radius $3*10^8 m + \Delta x$  after one second of observing, shouldn't the mass associated with it also have a probability cloud of radius $3*10^8m+\Delta x$.(e.g  electron)due to the combined effects of QM and GR. This doesn't violate any conservation law since the density is still finite and always remains finite. Also the density is time dependent then, which leads to the following problems.

1. It is practically impossible to calculate it by any means since the density is spread over very large distances.
2. How can we bring all this density into $\Delta x $ governed by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle with only minimal energy
3. If density is spread over such large distances , how can we calculate the mass of anything?

But electrons have existed since the dawn of universe so if an electron in an isolated part of the universe which has never whose wavefunction has never collapsed(it has never interacted with matter)  is found and somehow we calculate its QM mass density       $$  =\frac{3m_e}{4\pi (ct+\Delta x_i)^3}$$.
**t = age of universe**

$\Delta x_i$  = initial uncertainty in position $\approx 0$
So does this change in mass density have any visible consequences, can the difference be observed between this electron and another repeatedly observed electron?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think GR has anything to do with this, or why you think an electron put in an initial state of uncertainty $\Delta x$ in position has to spread outwards at the speed of light.

Comment: I only stating that the electron is 100% likely to be found   within $3*10^8m + \Delta x$

Comment: Well, why not take the denominator for your density to be the volume of the observable universe then? Also 100% likely.

Comment: @jacob1729 , that will not involve QM for sure. That's why I didn't ask a question from cosmology

Answer (score 1):

Note that the mass density of the electron and the mass density of the electron wavefunction  are not the same.

Still, suppose you can prepare two electrons and then measure the force between them after some time.   If you repeat this zillions of times (ensemble average) you will get a distribution in the magnitude of the force due to the uncertainty of the position of the electrons and hence the uncertainty of the distance between them.  (The density of the electron [if it has a finite density] remains the same.)